# How to get rid of the values already compared from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am trying to solve this problem.

> Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (compSame(a, b) in Clojure) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

After testing several times I am getting up to this state, Here is my function.

```
function comp(array1, array2) {

  let answer = [];
  let arrayToCompare = [];
  
  
  if(array1){
    array1.forEach((array) => {
      arrayToCompare.push(Math.pow(array, 2));
    });
    console.log(arrayToCompare);
    console.log(array2)
  }else{
    return false
  }
  
  if(array1 === null || array2 === null){
    return false
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayToCompare.length; i++) {
    if (array2.includes(arrayToCompare[i])) {
      answer.push(true);
    } else {
      answer.push(false)
    }
  }

  if (answer.includes(false)) {
    console.log(false);
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(true);
    return true;
  }
}
```

The problem from my function is that if there is duplicate values. This answer will come out incorrect

Example test case

```
array1 = [ 2, 2, 3 ]
array2 =[ 4, 9, 9 ]
```

this should return as false but  my functions is returning true. Can anyone suggest where i am missing &
how to optimize this function

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the problem:

```
 function comp(array1, array2) {
        return array2.sort((a,b) => a - b).join('-') === array1.sort((a,b) => a - b).map(item => item ** 2).join('-');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand you just remove every succesful checked in array2, so that it does not false positive on duplicates

```
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayToCompare.length; i++) {
    if (array2.includes(arrayToCompare[i])) {
      
      // if found, remove it from array2 so it will not be compared again
      array2.splice(array2.indexOf(arrayToCompare[i]), 1);
      
      answer.push(true);
    } else {
      answer.push(false)
    }
  }
```

I tested and it works fine with you given example data